# How to run multiple python versions using Apache and Gunicorn?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache, mod-wsgi, gunicorn

I have created a virtualenv to use python 3.4 and installed Gunicorn using pip3 along with the corresponding wsgi module.

I have started the python3 wsgi module using the command

```
mod_wsgi-express start-server --port 8101
```

And started Gunicorn at port 8100

In my apache virtual host config, I have the following

```
   WSGIDaemonProcess app \
    python-path=/var/www/django/virtualenv/app-env/lib/python3.4/site-packages \
    user=app_user group=app_group \
    processes=2 threads=15 \
    display-name=app

WSGIProcessGroup app
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/django/app/wsgi.py


<Directory /var/www/app>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

But Apache still is using Python 2.7.

Comment: gunicorn is an alternative to mod_wsgi, you wouldn't use them together. You can use Apache without mod_wsgi just as a reverse proxy for gunicorn, though.

Comment: And if using ``mod_wsgi-express``, you should also not be manually configuring Apache for the WSGI application. Same deal as gunicorn when using ``mod_wsgi-express``, have it behind Apache with Apache only acting as proxy.